# Show that there are at least

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> A $10\times10\times10$ cube has $1000$ unit cubes. $500$ of them are
>   coloured black and $500$ of them are coloured white. Show that there
>   are at least $100$ unit squares, being the common face of a white and
>   a black unit cube.

attempt: The extreme case which satisfies exactly 100 units square should be 500 black cubics up and 500 white cubics down. The black and the white meet only at the centre face which is exactly 100 units square.

Try to move any two cubics, one for black and one for white, the faces are gonna add up.

I believe that is the reasoning for an elegant and formalized answer. Thank you!

Comment: How have you proven that there cannot be a case with less than $100$ such unit squares?

Comment: @PeterForeman 
Notice that in each colune we have one comun face of tow diferent colored cubes or the colune has just cubes of the same color, and then we have, at least, more 1 comun sides of cubes diferente colored per neightbour colune or that colunes have cubes of the same colour.

Comment: Let us turn this problem in some 2 dimentional easy problem, so let us paint of black the top of the colunes that have just black cubes, respectivelly to the white cubes and the other colunes will gives us at least more one comun side. Therefor is easy to proof that all the black "zones" and white "zones" will have twhat we want to

Comment: After *one* step you have more than 100 unit squares, but that doesn't mean this is still the case after $n$ steps...